# Is there a way that team capacity in a Sprint is considered in forecasting and velocity?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I am trying to plan my Sprint based on the capacity of my sprint. Now it seems that, if I increase capacity of my team, the forecasting view in the Backlog does not consider the increased capacity in the future sprints - meaning the number of story points the team can manage stays the same for all Sprints - though they have different capacity?
Any idea if there is possibility that forecasting considerrs variable capacity of team?

Project Type: Agile, Estimate is in Story Points on Story Level, Forecasting is on Story Level.

Answer (score 0):

Teams use [the forecast tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/forecast?view=azure-devops) to help in their sprint planning efforts. Once your team has completed a sprint or two, they can use the team velocity to forecast how much of the backlog they can finish within the upcoming sprints.

If you work with several teams, and each team wants to work with their own backlog, velocity chart, and forecast tool, you can [create additional teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/add-teams?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page). Each team then gets access to their own set of Agile tools. Each Agile tool filters work items to only include those whose assigned area paths and iteration paths meet those set for the team.

See: [Determine the velocity needed to complete all items in the backlog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/forecast?view=azure-devops#determine-the-velocity-needed-to-complete-all-items-in-the-backlog) for details.